# MongoDB - How do I change the type of an string found in an array nested within a subdocument

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to change a type string to an Integer. The following code selects the right element when simply searching and the code works perfectly for string elements at the top.

```
db.providers.find({'assignments.assignment' : 
    {$elemMatch :
        {
            as_total_hours : 
                {$exists : true}}}}).forEach( function(obj) { 
                    obj.as_total_hours = parseInt(obj.as_total_hours); 
                    db.providers.save(obj); 
                })
```

Here is a sample of the document.

```
"dev_active_interviews" : 0,
"assignments" : {
    "assignment" : [ 
        {
            "as_rate" : "$3.89",
            "as_from" : "05/2011",
            "as_to"   : "Present",
            "as_total_hours " : "16"
        },
        {
            "as_rate" : "$2.22",
            "as_from" : "11/2010",
            "as_to"   : "Past",
            "as_total_hours" : "200"
        }
     ]
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is assuming that the `find` returns the embedded assignment objects rather than the object.

Change :

```
obj.as_total_hours = parseInt(obj.as_total_hours);
db.providers.save(obj);
```

to

```
obj.assignments.assignment.forEach(function(obj) {
    obj.as_total_hours = parseInt(obj.as_total_hours);
})
db.providers.save(obj);
```

You could also change the `{$exists:true}` to `{$type: 2}` (or combine them) so that the query only finds strings.